# Binaural Beats Meditation EEG versus Non-aided mediation EEG

Tags: meditation, brain-waves, binaural-beats

Can anybody point me to a recent scientific publication(s) that show the changes in a person's EEG using binaural beat meditation is similar to the EEG changes observed using traditional non-aided meditation.

Answer (score 3):

Theta and Alpha are the waves associated with meditation (KaKasamatsu & Hirai, 1966; Khare & Nigam, 2000).

Owen and Atwater found that:

> binaural auditory beats in the EEG alpha frequency range may increase
>   alpha EEG production and subjective relaxation

Furthermore On et al (2013) found that binaural beats could increase Theta activity:

> Binaural beat is the rhythmic stimulus which is generated to produce
>   the desired audio frequency with the intention to make brainwave to
>   follow that frequency. In the end of our research, the result shows
>   that Theta brainwave increases after listening to binaural beat.
>   Although the Delta brainwave is not really affected in this
>   experiment, there is still an increment of delta brainwave after
>   listening to binaural beat. The result shows that binaural beat
>   affected on delta and theta brainwaves.

I also found one from Lavallee (2011) that found the experienced meditators couldn't be hindered by binaural beats:

> Based on the results of this study, novice meditators were not able
>   to maintain certain levels of θ power in the occipital regions when
>   hindering binaural beats were presented, whereas when the facilitative
>   binaural beats were presented, the experienced meditators displayed
>   increased θ power in the left temporal lobe

Suggesting that the effect of binaural beats may not be as strong as long term meditative practise.

[Lavallee, C. F., Koren, S. A., & Persinger, M. A. (2011). A quantitative electroencephalographic study of meditation and binaural beat entrainment. The Journal of Alternative and Complementary Medicine, 17(4), 351-](http://online.liebertpub.com/doi/abs/10.1089/acm.2009.0691)355.

[On, F. R., Jailani, R., Norhazman, H., & Zaini, N. M. (2013, March). Binaural beat effect on brainwaves based on EEG. In Signal Processing and its Applications (CSPA), 2013 IEEE 9th International Colloquium on (pp. 339-343). IEEE.](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6530068/)

[Kasamatsu, A., & Hirai, T. (1966). An electroencephalographic study on the Zen meditation (Zazen). Psychiatry and Clinical Neurosciences, 20(4), 315-336.](http://is.muni.cz/www/178816/EEG_and_Zazen.pdf)

[Khare, K. C., & Nigam, S. K. (2000). A Study of Electroencephalogram in Mediators. Indian Journal of Physiology and Pharmacology, 44(2), 173-178.](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Baruch_Cahn/publication/7241255_Meditation_states_and_traits_EEG_ERP_and_Neuroimaging_Studies/links/0a85e532e79516ae2c000000.pdf)

Owens, J. E., & Atwater, F. H. (1995). EEG correleates of an induced altered state of consciousness: mind awake/body asleep. Submitted for publication.